# What should one do with an account hopper?

Tags: discussion

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/436637/ruchi
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/440417/jene
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/440457/jene
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/441249/sony
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/457085/sonya

I am quite confident it is the same guy because I subscribe to the [`Perl` tag on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl), so I easily notice that certain question topics, grammatic defects and idiosyncratic expressions (most notably "Please do help me") are recurring. Almost all questions are heavily edited to improve the English, so check the original revisions.

I conject the user is abandoning each account voluntarily after experiencing backlash (downvoted questions etc.). To preempt the obvious point of discussion, there also was no ban AFAICS. I haven't "called him on it" yet, i.e. reveal that I think I know that it's the same guy on different accounts.

Comment: It's possible that one or two of those accounts are blocked from asking further questions, creating a new account would get them around that block.  Down with the sweaty sock puppets!

Comment: @Andy - IIRC, that block is applied IP-wide; and, well - let's just say that more than one of these shares an IP

Comment: @Marc: ah, great stuff :-)

Comment: +1 for on-the-ball-ness

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on a number of factors / evidence, I'm content that this is all the same user. I've merged them accordingly. If I'm wrong in my conclusion; well, frankly we'll cross that bridge if-and-when.

Comment: I didn't know people can verify IP and that merging is possible; this answer exceeds my expectations! :thumb:

Comment: @daxim - we know everything... we've even despatched the chaps in suits to your home address to collect fingerprints and DNA. Of course, you could save us some time and just send us your fingers; solves both problems in one go.

Comment: Hey Marc, can you send me another bowl of ice cream? The last one melted before I could eat it all. I'll give you some more toenail clippings. You know I'm good for it.

Comment: @Toronto who are you kidding? there's most of a tub of fudge mint in your freezer - under the peas. It is a bit old though, so you might want to scrape off the top bit first.